Plotly Choropleth Map: Colors Not Mapping Correctly from Color Dictionary
I am trying to create a choropleth map using Plotly with a custom color dictionary, where specific states should be colored red and green. However, when trying to apply these colors, the chart is showing unexpected colors (such as pink and light blue) instead of the colors I defined in the dictionary.
The goal is to ensure that the states defined in the dictionary are colored red or green, while states not in the dictionary should be colored gray.
Code:
import geopandas as gpd
import plotly.express as px

# Path to the shapefile of Brazilian states
shapefile_path = 'brasil_estados.json'

# Load the shapefile using geopandas
brasil_mapa = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path, encoding='utf-8')

# Custom color dictionary (red and green)
color_dict = {
    'Minas Gerais': 'green',
    'Tocantins': 'red',
    'Amapá': 'red',
    'Roraima': 'red',
    'Goiás': 'red',
    'Distrito Federal': 'red'
}

# Map colors according to the dictionary
# If the state is not in the dictionary, it will be colored 'gray'
brasil_mapa['color'] = brasil_mapa['name'].map(color_dict).fillna('gray')

# Plot the map using Plotly
fig = px.choropleth(
    brasil_mapa,
    geojson=brasil_mapa.geometry.__geo_interface__,  # Using geometry directly
    locations=brasil_mapa.index,
    color='color',  # Color of the states based on the dictionary
    color_discrete_map=color_dict,  # Explicit color dictionary
    labels={'color': 'State'},
    scope='south america',
    title='Map of Brazilian States with Custom Colors',
    width=1200,
    height=800
)

# Adjusting map visualization
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)

# Show the plot
fig.show()




This may solve your issue:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63635104/plotly-how-to-set-choropleth-map-color-for-a-discrete-categorical-variable

In this case, the object to be mapped is the state name, so the color designation is 'name'. And we also need dictionaries for other than coloring, so we need to create dictionaries for all states.
color_dict = { k:v for k,v in zip(brasil_mapa[['name','color']].to_dict(orient='list')['name'],brasil_mapa[['name','color']].to_dict(orient='list')['color'])}

# Plot the map using Plotly
fig = px.choropleth(
    brasil_mapa,
    geojson=brasil_mapa.geometry.__geo_interface__,  # Using geometry directly
    locations=brasil_mapa.index,
    color='name',
    color_discrete_map=color_dict,  # Explicit color dictionary of all states
    labels={'color': 'State'},
    scope='south america',
    title='Map of Brazilian States with Custom Colors',
    width=1200,
    height=800
)

# Adjusting map visualization
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)

# Show the plot
fig.show()


